# C++ Quiz Questions

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract

I am practicing for an important quiz and I found 20 questions on c++ I am not very sure about. They came without answers and i wondered if you could help me answer them since I am still a rookie who is learning. I marked with an arrow the answer which i thought was correct for every wuestion with a brief reason.

#### QUESTION 1

```
class Base{
    protected:
        int a;
    public:
        void seta(int x){a = x;};
        void printa(void){cout << a;};
};

class SecondClass : public Base
{
    public;
        int b;
};

void main (void)
{
    Secondclass tmp;
    tmp.seta(12);
    tmp.printa();
}

a)SecondClass.a is public;
b)SecondClass.a is protected; <-- (Since SecondClass inherits from Base)
c)SecondClass.a is private;
d)SecondClass.a is not accessible;
```

#### QUESTION 2

What happens when the function foo() below is executed?
Assume bar() is an existing function.

```
void foo()
{
    Object *o = new Object;
    bar(o);
}

a) o is destroyed at the end of the scope of foo
b) o is not destroyed <-- (since there is no delete and o is a pointer)
c) o is destroyed if there is no exception in bar()
d) None of the above
```

#### QUESTION 3

Consider the following function declarations in a header file:

```
void doit(char *, int);
int doit(char *);
float doit(float, float);

Which of the following declarations cannot follow in the same header (no idea):
a) void doit(int, char*);
b) float doit(char *);
c) int doit(int, int);
d) int doit(int);
```

#### QUESTION 4

What is present in an abstract class that makes it abstract?

```
a) virtual keyword prefix o member function
b) virtual keyword prefixed to member function and sufixed with =0 <--(since without    the =0 it wouldnt be a pure virtual method which must be overriden)
c) member function in protected mode
d) any of the above
```

#### QUESTION 5

What is the result of the executing code fragment below?

```
//suitable #includes
class Text
{
public:
    Text(const std::string &text):data(new char[text.size()+1000]){
        std::copy(text.begin(),text.end(),data);
        }
    ~Text(){
        delete [] data;
        }
    void print() const{
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
        }
private:
    char *data;
};

int main(int, char *[])
{
    Text outer("hello");
    {
        const Text inner("world");
        outer = inner;
    }
    outer.print();
    return 0;
}

(No idea abou the answer)
a) prints "world", but there is a buffer overflow in the constructor
b) prints "world", no problems anywhere
c) prints "hello"
d) none of the above
```

Comment: There are too many questions in this post. Why don't you **choose one**, and focus on it (including what do you think the answer is), and after you are done with one - post a new question (if needed) for the second?

Comment: This is mostly pretty bad code. I wouldn't put any effort into making sense out of it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tons of questions

Comment: Only use a question here to ask one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Q1 OK
- Q2 depends on what do they mean by "o". In fact, "o" IS destroyed - it's a pointer on the stack, however the object pointed by o is not being destroyed.
- Q3 b) you can not overload on a return type
- Q4 OK
- Q5 because of the lack of the copy constructors d) seems most appropriate. However in practice, it is possible that it will output "world", even if this memory was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see.

1. Option b is indeed correct, but not your explanation. It's protected because `SecondClass` inherits from `Base` using public inheritance. Had it been private inheritance, this would not be so anymore.
2. Most likely correct. `o` is a pointer to an object created with `new`, and so the object will persist until `delete` gets called on it. The question probably refers to the object, but if they mean the actual pointer `o`, it gets destroyed at the end of the scope.
3. Overloaded functions must have different signatures. A signature consists of the function's name, and the count, type and order of arguments. Return type is *not* part of the signature. You should be able to figure it out from here.
4. An abstract class is a class that has at least one pure virtual function, so you are correct.
5. You can test it yourself and then think about why it happens. On my compiler for instance it prints "world" and crashes because of trying to delete memory twice.

Comment: 2.  Correction: `o` refers to *a pointer to* an object created with `new`.  Not the object itself.  The difference is part of the reason people get confused here.

Comment: Right, `o` is the pointer, and the question as stated is ambiguous. While the pointer gets destroyed at the end of the function scope, what the question likely means is the object pointed to by `o`.

Comment: What i'm saying is that your answer is currently muddling the two together.  It's saying `o` is the object.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers posted, in question 5 you have *undefined behavior*.

*{Language lawyers, please confirm the this issue}*
In the constructor, the characters are copied from the string one by one into a character array; *without a terminating nul character*.  The `print` method treats the array of characters as a C-style string and the `cout` operation will print all the characters in `data` (and beyond), until it finds a terminating nul character.  The `std::basic_string` data structure may not store a terminating nul character as part of the string.

There is no copy constructor for the class, so the compiler creates a copy constructor that copies the pointer.  Thus there will be two instances pointing to the same data.

In the inner block, the outer instance is assigned to the instance created in the inner block.  The inner instance is temporary and the pointer in the outer variable points to the data of a temporary object.

After the statement block disappears, the pointer in the outer variable is now pointing to a location that isn't used and the expected data isn't there anymore (the expected data was removed when the execution left the scope of the inner statement block).  Thus the `data` pointer of the `outer` variable is pointing to unknown data or unknown location (the OS may have paged out the data).  This is undefined behavior.

Comment: @BartoszKP - `new char[whatever]` does **not** initialize the allocated memory. Objects allocated with `new` are **default** initialized; for types that do not have constructors this means that no initialization is done.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I've deleted my comment, not to cause confusion.